# Permissions issue with all directories

Tags: permissions, mysql, root, sql, mariadb

I accidentally screwed up the permissions on my entire Ubuntu installation. While trying to fix an issue with inaccessible folders, I set all directories to be owned by root. I realize I will likely have to do a complete fresh install, but I am having trouble recovering the data from my Mariadb SQL database.

When trying to reinstall the service mariadb-server, I get the error:

```
 /usr/sbin/mysqld: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/mysqld: undefined symbol: pcre_stack_guard

 /usr/sbin/mysqld: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/mysqld: undefined symbol: pcre_stack_guard

 No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
 dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
 mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.0 (>= 10.0.26-2); however: Package mariadb-server-10.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

I am nearly certain this has to do with the permissions issues I have. How can I fix this and/or What is the best way for me to recover my InnoDB database?

Any help is much appreciated

Here is the console output if it helps: http://pastebin.com/yS5NeMXr

Comment: You left out the interesting parts of the output.

Comment: @ByteCommander Sorry about that. Updated with the full output from trying to install. Please let me know if there is any other information I can provide. (http://pastebin.com/yS5NeMXr)

Comment: Hmm... No idea what that all means. But I am worried that you seem to never ran an update as there are over 1000 not updated packages.

Comment: Real mysql keeps the db files in /var/lib/mysql/  - all owned by user 'mysql' - if that's any help. Nothing has 'other' access rights, some have 'drwxr-x---'. I tried mariadb but had trouble getting it to update & went back to the original, so can't be sure it's the same.